# android sqlite database delete query

Tags: android-sqlite

this is working delete but there is problem in data fetching after deleting the data and also problem comes data saving after deleting data

database class

```
     public void delete_byID(long id1)
     {
         Log.d("unicorn","in DELETE");
         db.delete(DATASAVE, _id+"-1="+id1, null);
      }
```

in activity i want to delete from profile activity and return to second activity

```
   delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
       {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            d1.delete_byID(id4);

    }
});
```

Comment: wat is ur ques . plz explain ur question properly

Comment: i m saving and delete data from database first i enter data then it's save in data base after that data is fetching is properly working then i apply delete query this is not working properly...so please tell me this code is correct or not

Answer (score 0):

put d1.delete_byID(id4) as first line in onClick(View v) method